# EC2 in VPC connectivity issues

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-vpc

I have a few ec2s in a public subnet (ie route table connected to the IGW) of my VPC.

The ec2s seem to have no ability to make http calls (it appears the call may go out but no response is recieved). There are currently no security rules (group and acls are set to allow all traffic in and out.

Because the ec2 is in a public subnet I would expect them to be able to make calls and receive responses.

Is there any way to grant the EC2s access to make outgoing http requests without assigning an ElasticIP or installing a NAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance in a public subnet needs one of two things to connect to the internet:  it must have a public IP address (which is not necessarily an Elastic IP) or there needs to be a NAT instance.

Your assumption that creating a routing rule to the internet for the subnet means instances can talk to the internet is incorrect:  there is no way for traffic to get back to your instance.

Since there is a difference between assigning an Elastic IP address to your instance and giving it a public IP address (the first you can keep associated with your account, and reassign if needed, the second you have no control over) technically the answer to your question is yes, you do this by assigning a public IP address to your instance.